# Не работает :checked в коде CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: верстаю header для мобильной версии сайта, сделал бургер меню, но почему-то не работает код который прописываю в псевдоклассе :checked.
То есть по дефолту блок .menu-items полностью скрыт, прозрачен, но если наш чекбокс :checked, то меню анимируется в крестик, а блок .menu-items стает непрозрачным, что я и сделал. Меню трансформируется в крестик, а вот блок не стает непрозрачным, он остается полностью невидимым.
Вот сам код:

```css
.mob_header_preview_wrapper{
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #0D606F 0%, rgba(13, 96, 111, 0) 25.1%), url(./assets/headerBackground.png);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  position: relative;
}
.mob_header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.mob_header_container{
  padding-bottom: 16%;
}
.mob_header nav{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.mob_header nav img{
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.checkbox{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  z-index: 200;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger-lines{
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 32px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.hamburger-lines .line{
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.hamburger-lines .line1{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.mob_header_preview_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hamburger-lines .line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 0.1px;
}
.mob_header_preview_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
.mob_header_preview_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-items {
  background-color: #F2785C;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5vw;
  height: 68%;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32%;
  left: 52%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .menu-items {
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu-items li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Red Hat Text';
  font-weight: 500;
}
.menu-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  margin: 0 0.7rem 0 0;
}
.menu-items a:hover {
  color: #aaa
}
section#mob_preview{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 15.5%;
}
.mob_preview_search{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255,255, .7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 1% 0;
}
.mob_preview_search span{
  font-family: 'Aleo';
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  color: rgb(242, 120, 92, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-left: 4.5%;
}
button[name="mob_start_planning"]{
  height: 4vh;
  min-height: 25px;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 4.5%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #0D606F;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 2px 3px rgba(13, 96, 111, 0.16);
  font-family: 'Red Hat Text', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.7vw;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}
button[name="mob_start_planning"]:hover{
  background-color: #167586;
}
```

```html
  <div class="mob_wrapper">

    <div class="mob_header_preview_wrapper">
      <header class="mob_header">
        <div class="mob_container mob_header_container">
          <nav>
            <a href="#"><img src="./assets/mobile_version/mobile_logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
            <div class="mob_nav_container">
              <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
              <div class="hamburger-lines">
                <span class="line line1"></span>
                <span class="line line2"></span>
                <span class="line line3"></span>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
          <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Plan Your Trip</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Travel Stories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
        </div>
      </header>
      <section id="mob_preview">
          <div class="mob_container"> 
            <div class="mob_preview_search">
              <span><i>What would you like to do?</i></span>
              <button type="button" name="mob_start_planning">Start planning</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

селектор `~` выбирает следующие соседние элементы

Через CSS вы не доберётесь за пределы родительского узла, только в соседние или в дочерние

Посмотрите пример здесь

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: pink;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .item {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

В вашем случае лучше сделать это через JavaScript

Comment: Всё вышло благодаря совету. Переместил меню в .mob_nav_container и все заработало, из-за абсолютного позиционирования никак ни на что не повлияло, спасибо.